# How to set gridview checkbox to checked when I click an asp:button in the same row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a gridview with a column of asp buttons that I toggle the text using javascript as follws:

```
function btnBuyToggle(objRef) 
{ 
    var row = objRef.parentNode.parentNode;
    var rowIndex = row.rowIndex;
    if (objRef.value == "ADD")
    {
        objRef.value = "REMOVE";
        $("#" + objRef.id).parent().parent().css("color", "#800080").css("font-style", "italic").css("background-color", "#F5FA61");
    } 
    else 
    {
      objRef.value = "ADD";
    }
}
```

Now I have added another gridview column of hidden checkboxes which I want to use for passing the toggled button instances back to the code behind on another button click event. So, what I need to do is modify the above script (JQuery is fine) to set the checkbox on the same row being toggled (checked for ADD button text values, and unchecked for the REMOVE button text values.

Here are my gridview fields:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Prior <br /> Downld" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" > 
    <ItemTemplate >
       <asp:Button id="btnBuy" runat="server" OnClientClick="btnBuyToggle(this); return false;"
             Text="ADD" CssClass="buyButton" Visible="true" />
     </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle Width="7%" />
    <ItemStyle CssClass="sessionOrderDownloadItems" VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="0px" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox Visible="False" Enabled="false" ID="buyCheckBoxHidden" runat="server"
             Checked='<%# Eval("SORD_SelectedForPurchaseFlag") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle Width="0px" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Thank you,
Jim

Here is my attempted fixed script:

```
      function btnBuyToggle(objRef) 
          { 
            var $btn = $("#" + objRef.id);

            if (objRef.value == "ADD")
            {
                objRef.value = "REMOVE";
                $btn.closest('.myClass').prop("checked", true);
                $btn.parent().parent().css("color", "#800080").css("font-style", "italic").css("background-color", "#F5FA61");
            } else {
                objRef.value = "ADD";
                $btn.closest('.myClass').prop("checked", false);
                $btn.parent().parent().css("background-color", "#FFFFFF").css("color", "#191970").css("font-style", "normal");
            }
        }
```

And my modified checkbox markup:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="0px" >
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:CheckBox style="display:block;" ID="buyCheckBoxHidden" runat="server" CssClass="myClass" Checked="false" />
   </ItemTemplate>
   <HeaderStyle Width="0px" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Thank you,
Jim

Comment: By the way since you are new to StackOverflow, you may want to take a look at these links: http://stackoverflow.com/faq and http://stackoverflow.com/privileges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first issue is that you have your checkbox set as `visible="false"`. When you do this, the checkbox will not be visible to javascript. You need to change it be `display:none`. Secondly, you can use the jquery [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to grab the closest checkbox. To make this easier you should probably add a class to your checbox. Once you have found the checkbox, you can use the jquery [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method to set the checked property to true or false.

**HTML**:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="buyCheckBoxHidden" Checked='<%# Eval("SORD_SelectedForPurchaseFlag") %>' style="display:none;" CssClass="class" />
```

Javascript:

```
function btnBuyToggle(objRef) 
{
    var $row = $(objRef).closest('tr');

    if (objRef.value == "ADD")
    {
        objRef.value = "REMOVE";
        $row.find('.myClass').prop("checked", true);
        // OR $row.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", true);
        $row.css("color", "#800080").css("font-style", "italic").css("background-color", "#F5FA61");
    } else {
        objRef.value = "ADD";
        $row.find('.myClass').prop("checked", false);
        // OR $row.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", false);
        $row.css("background-color", "#FFFFFF").css("color", "#191970").css("font-style", "normal");
    }
}​
```

Here is an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EVTRz/8/).

**Edit**:

By the way jquery [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) is the recommended way of changing property values for jquery versions 1.6 and later. If you are using an earlier version of jquery, you will need to use the [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method.

**Edit**:

Since it seems that the ASP.Net controls are removing your classes. FYI, ASP.Net controls have preset skins that can be found in your App_Themes folder and the theme you are using. Within the specific theme there is usually a Default.skin file that specifies what classes are on your controls by default. ASP.Net could possibly be removing your class when it creates the checkbox. You should search for the class that is added by ASP.net if you dont need to have your own class.

Comment: Yes, the checkbox is inside an INPUT which is inside a SPAN which is inside the last TD of the row. The myClass is there.  The myclass is on the SPAN, not the INPUT.

Comment: That works like a charm!  Thank you so much.  And you gave me a lot of knowledge about how to debug these types of things also.  Jim

Comment: Your Welcome! Glad to be of help!